# How to map location data on google map dynamically in asp.net through JSON string

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, google-maps-api-3

I'm displaying location on Google map with the following script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
var markersdetails = {
            "Iran": {
                "title": "Iran",
                "lat": "32.000000",
                "lng": "53.000000",
                "infodata": "sample 1"
            },
            "Italy": {
                "title": "Italy",
                "lat": "41.9000",
                "lng": "12.483",
                "infodata": "sample 2"
            }
        }
MapLocation(markersdetails);
});
function MapLocation(objmarkersdetails) {
//This function contains functionality to map location on google map
}
</script>
```

**This is working perfectly.**
Now I want to fetch location data dynamically from database so I write following code in code behind and make ajax call but **location data doesn't map/pinned on google map now**.

**Client Side**

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/utilities/GetLocation.aspx/GetLocationInJSON",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {
                var markersdetails = {};
                markersdetails = result.d;
                MapLocation(markersdetails);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert("Error" + error.responseText);
            }
        });
```

**Code Behind**

```
[WebMethod]
        public static string GetLocationInJSON()
        {
            StringBuilder sbLocation = new StringBuilder();
            //main start
            sbLocation.Append("{");
            sbLocation.Append("'Iran': {");
            sbLocation.Append("'title': 'Iran',");
            sbLocation.Append("'lat': '32.000000',");
            sbLocation.Append("'lng': '53.000000',");
            sbLocation.Append("'infodata': 'sample 1'");
            sbLocation.Append("}");
            sbLocation.Append("}");

            return sbLocation.ToString();
        }
```

I think through this approach **correct JSON string is not returning to client side**.
Could you please let me know is there something missing.

Thanks

Comment: You seem to just be building and responding with a `string` so check `result` (what is `result.d` in this case?) Hth..

Comment: result.d value is `{'Iran': {'title': 'Iran','lat': '32.000000','lng': '53.000000','infodata': 'sample 1'}}`

Comment: Where is the `MapLocation` function declaration and what is the content of `result` if you log it the ajax response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution here.Please have a look into this
http://forums.asp.net/p/1999448/5744936.aspx?p=True&t=635421113703022126&pagenum=1